# Knockout JS to highlight label or row which is checked in an array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a ticketing system which is written in KnockOut using template. Template structure is as below
This template is repeated for multiple users on a page. In this parent.AssignedTickets is a list of Ticket Id assigned to users. So system has multiple TicketIDs and if it is assigned to user then it shows checked.

I want to change label color if checkbox is checked.

```
<script type="text/html" id="TicketAssignmentTemplate">
    <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: TicketId, checked: $parent.AssignedTickets" />
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label data-bind="text: title"></label>
    </td>
</script>
<style>.success{background-color: #DFF0D8;}</style>
```

I tried data binding label css: {success: !$parent.AssignedTickets} but that did not work. Surprise! It can't be that simple. Any other thing I can try?

Comment: try `css: {success: !$parent.AssignedTickets()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking further at the questions, not really sure what you are trying to achieve by using the `$parent.AssignedTasks` observable array as a flag for both checked and to indicate success.  Not sure if the following answers you question, but this is how I would approach it.

Hope it helps

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Test 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Test 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Test 3'
  },
]



var Vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.AssignedTickets = ko.observableArray([]);
  var mappedTickets = data.map(function(item) {
    return new Ticket(item);
  })

  self.AssignedTickets(mappedTickets);

}

function Ticket(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.TicketId = ko.observable(data.id);
  self.title = ko.observable(data.title || '');
  self.assigned = ko.observable(false);

}

ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
```

```css
.success {
  background-color: #DFF0D8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="TicketAssignmentTemplate">
  <td>
    <label data-bind="css: {success: assigned}">
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: assigned" />
          <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
    </label>
  </td>
  
</script>



<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: AssignedTickets">
    <tr data-bind="template: { name: 'TicketAssignmentTemplate', data: $data }"></tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<ul data-bind="foreach: AssignedTickets">
  <li>ticket with Id :<span data-bind="text: TicketId"></span> is <span data-bind="if: assigned">assigned</span><span data-bind="ifnot: assigned">not assigned</span> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: $parent.AssignedTickets has data coming from database which is Ticked Ids already assigned. So I need to show it checked and colored when its loaded but when I check additional rows, $parent.AssignedTickets needs to be updated. Hence it is Observable array. When I submit the page, I use  $parent.AssignedTickets to update database for this user.

Comment: How do I attach screen shot here ?

Comment: "$parent.AssignedTickets"  is a KO Observable array of just Guids which are assigned to a user.
Template gets built first by second array which has Guids and Title of all tickets in the system. Then  checked: $parent.AssignedTickets shows tickets already assigned.